# batch file to search all .csv files in folder for string

Tags: batch-file

I have a lot of .csv files (that cames from an Oracle daily DB extraction) in a folder, and I need to search the files for the instances of the string:

`ERROR:

ORA-xxxxxx`

and return the whole line from each file and copy it to an output .txt file.

I've tried to search for the string `ERROR:` and if found search for the string `ORA-`, but the problem is that the files can have rows that contain the strings but these don't represent an Oracle error (ie. `JOHN MORA-***###***###` or `Mr xxx your line code has an ERROR: ...`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the two texts on the same line or in two lines?

Comment: Unfortunately they are on three lines. The first is ERROR: the second is a blank line and the third is ORA-xxxx

Comment: @k3b Look at the description on the `batch-file` tag.

Comment: @Stefanmo Show us what you've tried, then we can help you make it work.

Comment: I am using MSDOS (WinXp) and UnxUtils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    break > output.log

    for %%f in (*.csv) do findstr /r /c:"^ERROR:" /c:"^ORA-[0-9]*" "%%f" >> output.log
```

And for UnxUtils

```
grep -Eh "^(ERROR|ORA-[0-9]*)" *.csv > output.log
```

Comment: Wonderful! It suits well.

Comment: Many thanks. I was also able to use similar approach to search for the strings from multiple .csv files.

Answer (score 0):

```
findstr /l "Error:" *.csv|findstr /r "ORA-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]>output.txt
```

Above doesn't care what order the two search terms appear. You need to specify rules.

Are there under 64K lines in the file and are you 32 bit. See if edlin can help. If you have Win32 you could try scripting edlin. It has search and replace.

Edlin.script

```
12
Write new text on line 12
13
Write newtext on line 13
e
```

Command line

edlin "c:\something\somefile.txt < c:\edlin.script

Edlin uses short file names.